# Which NLS_DATE_FORMAT would be picked by the Stored Procedure

Tags: oracle, plsql

The NLS_date_format for database and session are as follows.

```
select * from nls_session_parameters : 
=========================
 DD-MON-YYYY

select * from nls_database_parameters: 
=============
DD-MON-RR
```

When my PLSQL procedure is called, which NLS_DATE_FORMAT would be picked? Will it be based on the current session date format or the database specified format.

Thank you taking time to make me understand the topic

Comment: The real answer to your question is: do **not** rely on `NLS_DATE_FORMAT`. Use `to_char()`  and `to_date()` with unambiguous format mask or use ANSI DATE literals. **Never** rely on implicit data type conversion

Comment: I accept @a_horse_with_no_name, but in the production the code relies on the NLS_DATE_Format. Though the session variable is set as 'DD-MON-YYYY' it is actually taking DD-MON-RR.

Comment: Then you should fix that bug in your production code.

Answer (score 4):

Session parameter will take precedence. From [NLS](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/NLS):

> **Note that session parameters take precedence over instance and database parameters.** Instance parameters take precedence over database parameters.

[Table 3-1 Methods of Setting NLS Parameters and Their Priorities](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10729/ch3globenv.htm#g1012681)

> ```
> +-------------+------------------------------------------------+
> |  Priority   |                     Method                     |
> +-------------+------------------------------------------------+
> | 1 (highest) | Explicitly set in SQL functions                |
> | 2           | Set by an ALTER SESSION statement              |
> | 3           | Set as an environment variable                 |
> | 4           | Specified in the initialization parameter file |
> +-------------+------------------------------------------------+
> ```

Comment: So by default the session parameters are taken into account when the Stored procedure is run? Even when we dont specify(using Alter session statement) them in the Stored procedure .

Comment: Session parameters have higher priority. `"Even when we dont specify(using Alter session statement) "` You may not use explicit `ALTER SESSION` but depending how you are connecting to DB your client/tool may set up these parameters. I propose to use explicit format with TO_CHAR/TO_DATE/...(highest priority and override session settings).

Comment: Even though not documented you may add `3.5 | Set by Registry (for Windows only)`. I think Environment variable takes precedence over Registry.